# c++ double more accuracy/precision

Tags: c++, double, precision, digit, mandelbrot

Is there any floating point type that stores more digits after the decimal point than `double` in c++ (or any alternative, which makes `double` stored more digits)?

I've read that `long double` is maybe more accurate.

In my program we can zoom into the Mandelbrot set, but after some zoom the picture gets pixelated. I think it is because the length between two complex numbers associated with two neighboring pixels is less than the difference between two consecutive value of double. In the program I used long double.

If it's important, then the processor of my computer is Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 380 @ 2.53GHz × 4, the computer is 64 bit, the operating system is Ubuntu and the compiler is gcc.

[image: the pixelated Mandelbrot set]

Comment: Have a read of this guy's blog posts on Fractals: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/fractals/

Comment: `long double` is more accurate if it's longer than `double`, which it isn't on many platforms. Check with `sizeof`. The Intel FPU computes in 80 bits.

Comment: The Mandelbrot set is non-computable. Which means that at some zoom your computer will give up, regardless of iterations or precision. But you can go to 80-bit doubles or even write your own routines in software.,

Comment: @MalcolmMcLean Really, it isn't computable ? Why is that ? Do you have a link to provide about this, please ?

Comment: The reason it is not computable is that it takes an infinite number of iterations to determine whether a point arbitrarily near the boundary is in or out of the set, and you can't close in on it logarithmically either.

Comment: Fixed point arithmetic can help, because the integral part can be assumed to be never larger than 4 (the square of +/- 2, at which the function value will escape).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at third party libraries like [boost.multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats.html) or even [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).

You can also do it "by hand" but that would be a lot of work. You would have to keep numbers as their string representation and manually make the arithmetic operations yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I will check them. String representation seems to be interesting. I know how addition and subtraction work, but multiplication and division are unknown for me. And if I knew them, I could make other functions with Taylor series e.g. sin, cos, x^y ... (I know I don't need these functions in my program). Logarithm is a question for me because its series converges within 1 radius.

Comment: If you feel like doing it by hand, go ahead, you'll learn a lot !